# Current list of safe PHP Practices?

Tags: web-application, php, sql-injection, mysql

I'm new to working with PHP, and recently inherited a website project where the original developer had been sanitizing user input with `mysqli_real_escape_string()` before querying the MySQL database. As I recently learned from [SQL Injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string/12118602#12118602)
, the database is still vulnerable to SQL injection into numeric fields, and prepared statements should be used instead.

I keep finding vulnerabilities like this one at a time, as I dig deeper into how PHP cleans, stores, and manages data. Most information I can find on the web is outdated by now, so it's difficult to find a list of current best practices. For my application, I need to store user passwords, allow logins with multiple permission levels, retrieve data from our database, allow users to submit various forms, etc.

Does anyone have a comprehensive and up-to-date list of best PHP practices for me to use as I program the website? If not, are you aware of common security mistakes that new PHP programmers make, and how to avoid them? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IMO this request is somewhat off-topic on SE because today's "current" list will be outdated in the near future, similar to product recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with [OWASP's Developer Guide](https://github.com/OWASP/DevGuide). Then just keep reading through other OWASP resources. Since you mentioned specifically PHP. Here is a [PHP Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet).

Another good read is SANS: "[security checklist for web app design](https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/securecode/security-checklist-web-application-design-1389)".

These should give you a good understand of building safe web sites/apps.